# Firebase Authentication Android fetchProvidersForEmail() bug?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to enable "Multiple accounts per email address", but I'm not really sure how it works. fetchProvidersForEmail() seems to return unexpected results.

I have the following code.

```
firebaseAuth.fetchProvidersForEmail("email").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<ProviderQueryResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ProviderQueryResult> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            List<String> providers = task.getResult().getProviders();
            if (providers != null) {
                Timber.d(providers.toString());
            } else {
                Timber.d("provider null");
            }
        } else {
            Timber.d("task fail");
        }
    }
});
```

**Scenario 1**

1. By default, sign in user with Google. `fetchProvidersForEmail()` returns `[google.com]`.
2. Enable "Multiple accounts per email address". `fetchProvidersForEmail()` returns `[]`.
3. Disable "Multiple accounts per email address". `fetchProvidersForEmail()` returns `[google.com]` again.

**Scenario 2**

1. Enable "Multiple accounts per email address". Sign in user with Email/Password first.
2. `fetchProvidersForEmail()` returns `[password]`.
3. Sign in user with Google. `fetchProvidersForEmail()` still returns `[password]` only.
4. Disable "Multiple accounts per email address". `fetchProvidersForEmail()` now returns `[google.com]` only.

**Conclusion**

1. When "Multiple accounts per email address" is not enabled, `[google.com]` is returned correctly. It is also given priority of Email/Password that was created when "Multiple accounts per email address" is enabled.
2. When "Multiple accounts per email address" is enabled, `[password]` is returned correctly. `[google.com]` is never returned.

Is this actually the correct behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Google Sign In has preference over other auth provider methods since a Google account is already regarded as verified by Firebase.

When multiple accounts are enabled, though, the first sign-in method associated with the email is returned.